# Preciso fazer com que meus botões mudem de cor apenas quando o ponteiro do mouse estiver sobre o botão

Tags: html, css

Com o código de css abaixo eu consigo mudar a cor dos cinco botões ao mesmo tempo, mas eu quero que mude apenas o botão onde o ponteiro do mouse esta, ou seja, se o ponteiro está no primeiro botão, apenas ele muda de cor e não os outros quatro.

```
nav#menu {
    display: block; 
}   
nav#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 300px;
}
nav#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #dddddd;      
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
nav#menu {
    display: block; 
}   
nav#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 300px;
}
nav#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #dddddd;      
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

nav#menu li:hover {
    background-color: red;      
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Opção 1</li>
    <li>Opção 2</li>
    <li>Opção 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
nav#menu li:hover{
   background-color: red;      
}
```

Falta declarar o [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) para o elemento **'li'**